# How to announce something that might be of interest to users of this site?

Tags: discussion, support

The puzzling StackExchange site has had several [MathJax-based puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/mathjax-exposed) recently, and I suspect that some users here (and at some other SE sites) might find them interesting.  What is the right way (if any) to inform the community of such items that appear on other sites?  These will not get enough traffic to warrant inclusion in the "hot questions" list.

I know that I've "cheated" and already informed this site of the puzzles, but that only works once, and I don't want to abuse the system.  Is there any approved way of doing that?

Comment: You could put an answer in whatever the current incarnation of the [community ads](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015) thread is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will look into that possibility.

Comment: You could ask again under the guise of "I asked this before, but I'm not sure whether the answer applies here and I wanted to announce such and such..."

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts, probably none of them is an ideal solution (and I hope that other users have more suggestions).

- As far as I know, moderators can add almost anything to the [community-bulletin](/questions/tagged/community-bulletin). (It does not have necessarily be a meta post. I have seen chat events in community bulletins and various other things.) But your announcement has probably to be important enough if you are going to persuade mods to pin it there.
- There is also chat. Admittedly it will get less visibility than meta. The [main chatroom at math.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics) currently has 600 messages per day. It means that unless somebody stars or pins your message, it will be only visible for a short time. But there are other rooms associated with this site which have less traffic. (They are usually devoted to specific topic, so the announcement might not be a good fit.) Just to show the contrast, I will mention that [MathOverflow main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9369/mathoverflow) has less than one message a day. So you will be choosing between visibility for a longer time or more users of the chatroom.
- There are also chat events, which are more prominently visible. But in this case you would have to organize chat event associated with your announcement.
- If this is suitable for our [blog](/questions/tagged/blog), you could write there.
- And again, there is meta. On some occasions posts which were clearly off-topic were tolerated here in the past if the topic was of importance. (Or at least left open for a longer time than a usual off-topic post.) Example: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17330/death-of-grothendieck It seems that MO has more tolerance to such things on their meta. Examples: [Grothendieck -sad news](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187106/grothendieck-sad-news) and [MathOverflow user jailed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2797/mathoverflow-user-jailed). However, all examples I listed above were eventually closed or locked.

The suggestions I have given above coincide to some extent with the generic part of my answer here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22822/how-to-promote-explanation-of-closure-in-comments/22823#22823

Comment: Yes, none of these seem ideal, but are good suggestions given the options available.  I think the blog might be the most appropriate choice.

Comment: @Davide meta.mathoverflow also has this thread, which I think is in no danger of being closed: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3144/news-of-potential-interest-to-the-mo-community Most of the posts there announce the passing of prominent mathematicians.